# Does GDPR restrict handling data that the user has certified is not personal information

Tags: gdpr

If my site ToS has this:

> By submitting data to the this site, you certify that the data is not of a nature that would cause me to have any special obligations under applicable law.

And someone from Europe submits personal information, am I obligated to remove it?

Comment: What sort of data does the site accept?  No magical incantation can stop your users' passport numbers -- or even survey responses about preference for sparkling or flat bottled water -- from being personal information.  Users can permit you to process their data, but they cannot change the nature of the data with respect to the GDPR.

Comment: @phoog it allows users to upload arbitrary text, but it's intended for one very narrow purpose that does not include personal information. Unfortunately it isn't feasible to validate the data. Users are supposed to only use one particular client program, but it will be open source, so there's no way to technologically enforce that.

Comment: You do not have to validate anything. You just have to comply when users want it deleted. The easiest way would be to give users the option to edit or delete all of their data themselves and not keep (technically not required) backups. Problem solved.

Comment: Do you imagine that the GDPR prevents the storage of personal data altogether, or are you asking whether you would have to remove it on request from the user who uploaded it?

Comment: If a user can't prove to me that they uploaded the data, e.g. because the computer with the proof quit working, am I still obligated to delete?

Comment: @nvoigt it's not quite that simple, because users don't have accounts for privacy. (It's weird that a design decision made to protect user privacy is making it hard to comply with a privacy law.) I guess I could have my server send a randomly generated token to the client, and the client could save that, and the user could use it later to have the data removed?

Comment: Without something like that I could not distinguish between Alice requesting that I take down her data for privacy and Bob requesting that I take down Alice's data maliciously. If people use the service as intended, though, there will be no PII.

Comment: "Without something like that I could not distinguish between Alice requesting that I take down her data for privacy and Bob requesting that I take down Alice's data maliciously": whatever you do, don't make your site available to the public without hiring a lawyer.  But consider the possibility that Bob _posts_ Alice's PII and Alice requests its deletion.  In that case I suppose you may have to delete it.  If that's true, then the identity of the poster doesn't matter, only the identity of the person whose PII it is.

Comment: @phoog good point. The service is completely non-essential; maybe I'll just let anyone delete any data.

Comment: The user has to prove that he has a right to demand deletion, and without a user account it seems quite difficult for them to prove it. So the question seems moot (but then there might be other laws that might apply, e.g. if your users use your platform to spread libel, the libeled subject might have a right to have this removed. But that would not be GDPR related).

Comment: @EikePierstorff that's why I'm thinking it might be better to let anyone remove any data. The service will have little practical use and is mostly "just for fun," so someone maliciously deleting data will cause little more than an annoyance.

Comment: @Someone a service that allows to share random stuff anonymously on the internet is certainly a very bad idea full of legal pitfalls. Privacy is probably the last of your potential issues.

Comment: @EikePierstorff how do pastebin sites get away with it? Or Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Someone I don't know about pastebin, but SE has lawyers.  They also have user accounts, unlike your site, so their model is more in line with the classic social media model that the GDPR takes into account.

Comment: @phoog oh, okay. Maybe I'll just write the software and let people run their own servers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This question shows a misconception of GDPR.

- GDPR creates an obligation not just towards the *data subject* but also towards the authorities of the relevant state(s). The data subject cannot waive your responsibility to safeguard data, document internal processes, etc.
- GDPR is not a blanket ban on the handling of personally identifying information (PII). Informed consent is one of the ways to get permission to process and store this data. If your *data subjects* are prepared to give your sweeping permissions, ask for consent (informed, revocable, etc.), document the consent, and go from there.
- The *data subject* does not get to decide what classification data falls under. If you collect, say, medical data, then you *are* subject to increased restrictions and safeguards.

Comment: Indeed, it's hard to imagine how one could argue that a user uploading arbitrary text to a website somehow withholds permission for the website to process the text.

Comment: @phoog, GDPR requires that the website clarifies **what** it does with the text (e.g. third party use, user profiling, ..., or mere storage without further processing). So the scope of consents should be made explicit.

Comment: @phoog Undere the GDPR consent must be explicit, it may not ever be implied by uploading information. It must also be revocable.It must also be freely given, and the provision of services should not depend on such consent.

Comment: @DavidSiegel the whole point of my service is to share non-personal information. I'm concerned that someone will share personal information anyway.

Comment: @Someone, do you know what GDPR considers to be PII? User names, IPs, things like that. Do you plan to work without logged-in users?

Comment: @o.m. yes, it will be a no-account service. Users will be able to anonymously submit data. No PII should be uploaded, and IPs won't be logged except as needed for security. My only concern is that users might upload PII anyway, despite the ToS.

Comment: For example, say you let visitors to your web site post an anonymous message (similar to the old guest books on 1990's web sites). The site makes it clear that such messages will be publicly visible. One visitor posts their name. What obligations does the GDPR place upon you? Do you have permission to have it, because the site said it would be public? I suppose you must have a process in place to delete messages upon request?

Comment: @DavidSiegel I understand that consent must be explicit.  But if a user understands what's going to be done with some text they upload, at some point it is the user's responsibility to understand whether they want to include, for example, their biographical data in that text.

Comment: @DavidSiegel but note that consent may be "a clear affirmative action" that "signifies agreement to the processing of personal data," so as long as the uploader is properly informed, the fact of the upload may be a component of the consent.

Comment: @Corrodias Note that the PII would be **only** the name. So *at most* you'd be required to change the name with "<redacted>" for example, but you have no obbligation to remove the whole message. (Although it's obviously technically easier to simple delete whole messages instead of having to parse them to modify certain portions).

Comment: @GACy20, PII can be much more general than just a name. Say you have a forum about photography. If an user posts the serial number of his or her camera, **that would be PII**.

Comment: @o.m. I don't follow what you are saying. Corridias made a specific example of how you'd handle a message that contains a name. My point is that you don't *have* to delete the whole content if the user requests deletion of their data, you just have to remove the PII. The user does *not* automatically have the right to remove all the content they create on a platform they use just because part of it contains PII. Once they register they usually accept the terms which include the licensing of their content to the platform (which is usually a complete, perpetual, irrevocable license).

Comment: @GACy20 PII is an US term, the GDPR's concept of personal data is much broader. Personal data is any information relating to an identifiable person. If the commenter is identifiable, then the whole comment is personal data as well. But the right to erasure isn't absolute and contains many exceptions.

Comment: @amon I have taken GDPR training annually for a few years, due to employment by an internationally-active corporation. "Personally identifiable information" is what the training says matters (anything that can be used to identify the data subject), which does not necessarily include all data that the data subject submits. GACy20 appears to be correct: "yes, it counts" and "yes, you must have such a process" (onerous!). My team doesn't collect user-submitted, freeform text, so I hadn't thought about it much, before.

Comment: @Corrodias Personal data is a GDPR term of art. If your training uses other terms with other definitions then I'm not sure how it relates to GDPR. I recommend the [UK ICO's guidance on *What is personal data?*](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-data-protection/guide-to-the-general-data-protection-regulation-gdpr/key-definitions/what-is-personal-data/) as a starting point for understanding the GDPR's definition. While GACy20 and I arrive at similar conclusions (pseudonymizing the comment might be OK), we give very different reasons (it's not PII vs right to erasure is not absolute).

Answer (score 10):

Yes. Assuming you fall under the GDPR.

You are by law required to remove it if requested (and no other law overrides this, for example if you need it for billing or taxes or other legal obligations).

The fact that your user broke your terms of service is between you and your user and cannot undo existing laws. You can do whatever you do when users break your terms of service, but you do not get to break the law by keeping the information.

Compare for example if someone sells you stolen goods. The fact that they lied and told you the goods were legit does in no way mean you get to keep them. Someone making false claims does not mean the laws around it are null and void. They still exist and they still take precedence over "but they said so!".

Comment: "*You are by law required to remove it if requested*" This is true only if none of the exceptions in the GDPR itself applies, and they are not limited to "*if you need it for billing or taxes or other legal obligations*"

Comment: @DavidSiegel Also billing and legal obbligations **ARE** valid exceptions, since their certainly fall under "legitimate business interest&need". Most countries force you to store invoices for something like a decade, invoices *do* contain PII and no amount of GDPR will force someone to delete their invoices since they are legally obligated to keep them.

Comment: @GACy20 Yes, quite true, That is why I wrote "*...not **limited** to...*"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make your users waive their legal rights for no good reason.

It's still a good idea to state in the ToS that users are not allowed to submit PII in certain forms. Such submissions can still happen of course, but having a "no private data allowed" rule gives you a good reason to remove the problematic content without upsetting your users.

"Letting anyone delete their own content" doesn't solve the problem, user A could use your service to post B's personal data, and you'll still have to deal with B's complaint.

"Letting anyone delete any content" is so prone to abuse that it'll be probably easier to deal with a GDPR complaint once in a while, than to explain to users why their data is gone.

Auto-deleting the content after a few days will be a much cleaner strategy with the same effect of practically avoiding GDPR complaints.

And BTW, you actually **want** to collect some private data about your users if you host their data, even for a few days. If user A posts B's credit card info, it will not be sufficient for B to have it removed. If B's information was used to steal their money, and B finds this information on your site, you'd better have A's PII when the police shows up.